# find maximum $l$ where $ l \ge 0 $ and $ l\le k$ such that $\gcd(a_0 ,a_1 ,...,a_n,l)>1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

> Our task is to find maximum $l$ where $ l \ge 0 $ and $ l\le k$ such that   $$\gcd(a_0 ,a_1,...,a_n,l)>1.$$

Solution to problem says that $l=k-(k\bmod g)$ so we can iterate through all divisors of $ \gcd(a0 ,a1 ,a2 ,.... ,an)$  and  For each divisor, calculate the largest l such that $\gcd(a0, a1,a2,.... an)$ evenly  divides $l$ , then choose the maximum among them.

HERE $a_0 ,a_1, ... ,a_n$ are numbers we already know.

I could not understand as how this solution is right ? can anyone explain it more clearly?

Comment: @GerryMyerson don't downvote it .it will be good if u can explain it

Comment: Have you tried seeing how it works in an example? Pick some numbers, say, $a_0=72$, $a_1=120$, $a_2=180$, and use the method of the solution and see what happens.

Comment: yes it works to fine . gcd(72,120,180)=12 and if k=10                                            
    l=10-10%2=10
l=10-10%3=9
l=10-10%6=6
l=10-10%12=0
and so max l=10 but still the intution is not clear .

Comment: If $\,d\,$ is the gcd of the $\,a_i\,$ then  take the gcd of $\,d\,$ with $\,l = k,\, k\!-\!1,\, k\!-\!2,\ldots$ till you get a gcd $> 1\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the largest integer less than or equal to $k$ that shares a prime divisor with the number $N$, where $N=\gcd(a_1,a_2\dots a_m)$.

So the numbers you have to consider are $p\lfloor\frac{l}{p}\rfloor$, where $p$ is a prime dividing $N$. The answer is the maximum of these numbers.